# How to start windows after having installed Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: windows

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a separate partition. However, when i turn on my computer there is no option to start windows - actually there is no option at all, it just starts Ubuntu automatically.

so, how can i go to windows again?

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu then run `sudo update-grub` command on terminal(ctrl+alt+t). That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu 14.04 and try updating Grub from terminal(ctrl+Alt+T)

sudo update-grub

That will check for the other OS that are installed in your machine and updates grub then reboot to see if it worked

If that did not work then you have to repair your windows boot-loader first and then re-install grub

for windows boot loader

=> u need a windows 8 repair disc or windows 8 live usb or live cd

boot from any of the above windows disc and go to

Repair=>System Recovery Options=>command prompt

type the following two commands in cmd exactly

Bootrec/fixmbr 'press enter'

Bootrec/fixboot 'press enter'

now reboot u can see windows boot loader again

Now back to grub boot loader

=> u need ubuntu live usb and use " load ubuntu without install" then install boot-repair and repair grub u can see it in this how it is done https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

if u install windows boot loader u can create a ubutnu live usb in windows using unetbootin(in case if u have a single pendrive currently)

Comment: well, i don't have a windows cd. think i'll just remove windows from my computer anyway. thank you

Answer (score 0):

assuming that windows is in first partition, and Ubuntu is in other partition, you can run grub update command.

run this command: "sudo update-grub"

it will ask for password, type your password in it, wait for some time.